# How does an acid prevents or discourges oxidation of iron?

Tags: redox, titration

In the titration of $\ce{KMnO4}$ with Mohr's salt, I have learned that sulphuric acid prevents oxidation of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ to $\ce{Fe^3+}$ in the solution before the actual titration. How does the acid hampers oxidation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is largely due to the extreme insolubility of iron (III) hydroxide, i.e. $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$.

One can write the oxidation reaction, somewhat simplified, as:

$$\ce{Fe^2+(aq) + 6 H2O(l) <=> Fe(OH)3(s) + 3 H3O+(aq)} + e^-$$

The $K_{sp}$ (solubility product) value for $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ is very small: $2.79 \times 10^{-39}$ (Wikipedia).

From the equilibrium reaction it's easy to understand that acidic conditions (high $[\ce{H3O+}]$) push the equilibrium to the left, thus preventing the oxidation.

It also explains why [Mohr's Salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_iron(II)_sulfate) resists oxidation much better than simple ferrous sulphate, as the ammonium ion provides some acidity.

In alkaline conditions the oxidation of ferrous ions to ferric ions is very fast.

Comment: Yes, I understood you used the Le Chatelier's Principle on the reaction. That answers my questions. But why does extreme insolubility has a role to play in this.

Comment: Well, *precisely because of Le Chatelier*. As precipitation removes $\ce{Fe^3+}$, the equilibrium shifts toward more $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$. Lower solubility obviously promotes precipitation.

Comment: I'll put a bit of 'mathematical meat' on this answer tomorrow.

Comment: Tomorrow never came...

Comment: Would you still like me to add that part?